# Problem understanding how to, if at all possible, run my docker file (.tar)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, github, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04

I received a .tar docker file from a friend that told me that it should contain all dependences for a program that I've been struggling to get working and that all I need to do is "run" the Docker file. The Docker file is of a .tar format and is around 3.1 GB. The program this file was setup to run is call opensimrt. The GitHub link to the file is as follows:
https://github.com/mitkof6/OpenSimRT

The google drive link to the Docker file is as follows:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M-5RnnBKGzaoSB4MCktzsceU4tWCCr3j/view?usp=sharing

This program has many dependencies, some big ones to note is that it runs off ubuntu 18.04 and Opensim 4.1.
I'm not a computer scientist by any means, so I've been struggling to even learn to do docker basics like load and run a image. However, I desperately need this program to work. If you have any steps or advice on how to run this .tar I'd greatly appreciate it. Alternatively if you are able to find a way to get opensimrt up and running and can post those steps I'd be more than happy with that solution as well.

I've tried the commands "docker run" and "docker load" followed by their respective tags, file paths, args..etc. However, even when I fix various issues I always get stuck with a missing var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-import-....(random numbers) file. The numbers change every so often when trying to solve the issue, but eventually I always end up getting some variation of this error: Error response from daemon: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-import-3640220538/bin/json: no such file or directory.

ps: I have extracted the .tar already and there is no install guide/instruction, .exe, install application. As a result I'm not sure how to get the program installed and running.

Comment: The .tar is an archive, you have to extract it first

Comment: I have extracted the .tar. However, there is no .exe or install application. As a result I'm not sure how to mount, install, or run the program on a vm or on windows.

Comment: you run docker from the command line generally, have a read of this.  I use linux so sorry I can't help much more. https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/docker-tutorial/install-docker-on-windows#:~:text=To%20start%20docker%20desktop%2C%20first,add%20particular%20components%20on%20windows.